# Teradata client on Unix Solaris

Tags: sql, shell, command, teradata

I deploy some .bteq and .sql scripts on a TERADATA database. For doing this, I use a client on my desktop called BTEQWin version 13.10.0.03.

I get the .bteq/.sql from a version control like pvcs/svn etc and all I do once the files are in my workspace folder (from Version control tool), to just drag and drop the files from Windows browser to BTEQWin client (which I connect to a database prior to drag/drop for running those scripts).

Now, I have to automate this whole process in UNIX.

I have written a SHELL KSH/BASH script which is getting all the .bteq/.sql from a TAG/LABEL in the version control tool to a given UNIX folder. Now, all I need to do is the pass these files one by one (i'll take care of the order) to Teradata client.

My ?
- what client do I need to tell Unix admin team to install on Unix server - so that I can run something like below:

someTeraDataCommand -u username -p password -h hostname -d database -f filenametoexectue | tee output_filename.log

Where, someTeraDataCommand is the client / executable - which will let me run Teradata scripts (like I was doing using BTEQWin on my desktop - GUI session). Other parameters can be username, password, which database to connect on what server and which file to run or make that file passed to the command using "<" operator at command line.

Any idea?
- What client ?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the complete Teradata Tools and Utilities package is installed on your UNIX server (which will have the connectivity tools to talk to Teradata), you should have access to `bteq` from the command line.  Something like this:

```
bteq < script_file > output_file
```

Your script file should contain a `.LOGON` statement to establish the connection:

```
.LOGON yourTDPID/your_account,your_pw
```

You might also need to use other commands to set your default database or non-default session values.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. So, should I tell Unix Admin team to install + "Teradata Tools and Utilities" and "Connectivity Tools" package (which are included in the former package) on the machine?

Comment: One more ?, I was assuming that there should be only a "client" that one can install instead of installing the whole software package. Can you please correct. Thinking in the sense that if I work with Visual Studio client, then if I'm not a developer, then I dont the the full VS package installed on my machine, I can just live with Team Explorer client (which is very light weight) and does everything.

Comment: Yes, you should ask your UNIX admins to install the Teradata Tools and Utilities (TTU) package associated with the version of Teradata you are running.  TTU is a bundle of several items some of which are required to communicate with the database from the server.  bteq is one of the included tools.  Note that these are all "clients"; they are not the database itself.

Comment: Hey Bob, When I'm running "bteq < script_file > output_file" on the $ prompt, it's not working. The script_file does contain ". logon dbname/dbuser,dbpasswd" Do I need to provide . logon .... first and then call my script_file? or what if script_file contains the ". logon .." line as well.

Comment: In what way does it not work?  The file named "output_file" should contain any messages created by executing the script.  If it shows some problem, you might want to ask a new question here on SQ.

Answer (score 0):

Another option would be to combine the SQL and call to BTEQ in a Korn shell script:

```
#!/usr/bin/ksh
##############
SHELL_NAME=`basename $0`
PRG_NAME=`basename $(SHELL_NAME} .ksh`
LOG_FILE=${PRG_NAME}.log
OUT_FILE=${PRG_NAME}.out
#
bteq <<EOBTQ > ${LOG_FILE} 2>$1

.LOGON {TDPID}/{USERID},{PWD};
--.RUN file=${LOGON}

/* Add your SQL/BTEQ commands here */

.QUIT 0;

EOBTQ
```

**Edit**

The double hyphen indicates a single line comment. Typically in a UNIX script you do not leave your password in plain text of a KSH script. The .RUN command would reference a text file in a barely sufficient secure location containing the `.LOGON {TPDID}/{USERID},{PWD};` command.

The .RUN command in BTEQ allows you to reference another text file containing a series of valid BTEQ commands that you want to run in the current BTEQ script.

Comment: Thanks Rob, Do I need to prefix "--" before .RUN ?

Comment: Added some additional clarification to the answer instead of in the comment section.

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way is to setup the Solaris TTU, is to request root sudo, and run an interactive installation into defaults as a root. That would cure all client issues.